# Can't open a recipe from a flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been making a recipe app that gets the data from an api. The app has a search and the search it self works but i can't open the recipe page. The opening works on home page but not in search.

This is List.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import styles from "../styles/styles";
import RecipeCard from "./RecipeCard";

const List = ({ searchPhrase, setClicked, data, navigation, screen }) => {
  const formattedSearchPhrase = searchPhrase.trim().replace(/\s/g, "").toUpperCase();

  const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
    const formattedItemName = item.name?.trim().replace(/\s/g, "")?.toUpperCase();
    const formattedItemDetails = item.details?.trim().replace(/\s/g, "")?.toUpperCase();

    return formattedItemName?.includes(formattedSearchPhrase) || formattedItemDetails?.includes(formattedSearchPhrase);
  });

  const openRecipePageFromList = (recipe) => {     
    console.log('Navigating to screen:', recipe.screen); // Add this line to print the screen name to console
  
    if (screen === 'SearchScreen') {
      navigation.navigate('SearchRecipePageScreen', { recipe: recipe });
    } else if (screen === 'FavoritesScreen') {
      navigation.navigate('FavoritesRecipePageScreen', { recipe: recipe });
    }
};

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const itemName = item.name?.trim();
    const itemDetails = item.details?.trim();

    if (!itemName && !itemDetails) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <RecipeCard
        key={item.id}
        recipe={{ name: itemName, details: itemDetails, thumbnail_url: item.thumbnail_url }}
        screen={'SearchScreen'}
        onPress={() => openRecipePageFromList(item)}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.list__container}>
      <View
        onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {
          setClicked(false);
        }}
      >
        <FlatList
          data={filteredData}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          extraData={searchPhrase}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default List;
```

And this is RecipeCard.js which are displayed on the list in search

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import styles from '../styles/styles';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function RecipeCard({ recipe, screen }) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkFavorite = async () => {
            try {
                const storedFavorites = await AsyncStorage.getItem('favoriteRecipes');
                if (storedFavorites !== null) {
                    const parsedFavorites = JSON.parse(storedFavorites);
                    const found = parsedFavorites.some((favRecipe) => favRecipe.id === recipe.id);
                    setIsFavorite(found);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        };
        checkFavorite();
    }, [recipe.id]);

    const openRecipePage = () => {
        if (screen === 'HomeScreen') {
            navigation.navigate('HomeRecipePageScreen', { recipe: recipe });
        } else if (screen === 'SearchScreen') {
            navigation.navigate('SearchRecipePageScreen', { recipe: recipe });
        } else if (screen === 'FavoritesScreen') {
            navigation.navigate('FavoritesRecipePageScreen', { recipe: recipe });
        }
    };

    const handlePress = async () => {
        try {
            const storedFavorites = await AsyncStorage.getItem('favoriteRecipes');
            let favoriteRecipes = [];
            if (storedFavorites !== null) {
                favoriteRecipes = JSON.parse(storedFavorites);
            }
            if (isFavorite) {
                const index = favoriteRecipes.findIndex((favRecipe) => favRecipe.id === recipe.id);
                if (index > -1) {
                    favoriteRecipes.splice(index, 1);
                }
            } else {
                favoriteRecipes.push(recipe);
            }
            setIsFavorite(!isFavorite);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('favoriteRecipes', JSON.stringify(favoriteRecipes));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={openRecipePage}>
                <View style={styles.recipeCardContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                        <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: recipe.thumbnail_url }} />
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
                        <Icon
                            name={isFavorite ? 'heart' : 'heart-outline'}
                            size={24}
                            color={isFavorite ? 'red' : 'black'}
                            style={styles.heartIcon}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.recipeCardTextFrontPage}>{recipe.name}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I still think the problem is probably that the code can't find the recipe i'm trying to open and where i'm trying to open it from but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: And it doesn't do anything? Maybe add logs in your `openRecipePage` to see what's going on.
From what I understand, it should open `SearchRecipePageScreen`, do you have this route in your app ?

Comment: it only gives me 'cannot read property map of undefined' when i try to press a recipe. i have proper routes

Comment: There is no map in your code. Are you sure the error is not elsewhere ? It doesn't show the line error ?

Comment: No it doesnt thats why i think this is so weird

Comment: Can you add some code you have or provide the screenshot of your error ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
    return (
  <RecipeCard
    key={item.id}
    recipe={item}
    screen={'SearchScreen'}
  />
);
```

Simple fix eventually.